# Password useless in cnosdb

Tags: cnosdb

1. Set config file `auth_enabled = false` and start cnosdb
2. Login consdb-cli as root, change password:

```
ALTER USER root SET PASSWORD = 'aaa';
```

3. Restart cnosdb, with config file setting `auth_enabled = true`
4. Login consdb-cli as root without password, it still managed to log in.